# Adding elements to an arraylist on an event hundler

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm Trying to create a new object of Path type each time the mouse is released and add it an ArrayList, so that i could use it later to allow creation of many Paths with different colors and it would be helpful in creating Undo/Redo.
but adding new element to the ArrayList inside an event handler doesn't seem to work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Source extends Application {

    public static ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);
        for(int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
          root.getChildren().add(paths.get(i));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        Path path = new Path();
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED){   
                path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
            }
            else if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED){
                path.getElements().add(new LineTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
            }
            if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == mouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED){
                paths.add(path);  
            }   
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: well `path` would go out of scope before it can be added to `paths` Maybe declare `path` at the class level as a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Source extends Application {
    public static ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                Path path = new Path();
                paths.add(path);
                path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(event.getX(),event.getY()));

                scene.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(event.getX(),event.getY()));
                    }
                });
                root.getChildren().add(path);
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I've figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
public class Source extends Application {

    public static ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);
        for(int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
          root.getChildren().add(paths.get(i));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    Path path = new Path();
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED){   
                path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
            }
            else if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED){
                path.getElements().add(new LineTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
            }
            if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == mouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED){
                paths.add(path);
            }   
        }
    };
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it didn't work, but thanks anyway for your effort :)

Comment: why do `path = new Path();` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat just to reset it though I think there is another way